# If the level set of real valued function f(x,y,z) is a curve then will ContourPlot3D fail to plot points?

Tags: plotting

I have the function $f(x,y,z)=\frac{x^2}{2}+x y+\frac{y^2}{2}+z^2$.  The solution set to the equation $f(x,y,z)=0$ is the line parametrized as $(t,-t,0)$.  When I use ContourPlot3D on f=0 I get an empty graph.  I begin to suspect that ContourPlot3D only works for level sets that are surfaces.  Is this correct?

Comment: `ContourPlot3D`returns a surface, it doesn't return oneparametric curves.

Comment: @Ulrich:  Are you saying that if the level set can be parametrized using a single parameter then ContourPlot3D fails to detect any points on the graph?  It can't know in advance whether or not a level set can be parametrized using a single parameter.

Comment: In the documentation you'll find  `ContourPlot3D visualizes the surface` and `ContourPlot3D is also known as a level surface or iso surface`. Same with `ContourPlot` which can't find points as contour.

Comment: If you write the function as: 1/2 (x+y)^2 + z^2 you see at once, that the solution is x==-y. and then z==0, what is not imaginary. Therefore, the solution is a straight line. And I think `ContourPlot` simply misses the 1 dim. line during sampling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ContourPlot3D` can only render surfaces, but in your case you can approach the 1D solution this way :

```
ContourPlot3D[(x + y)^2 + z^2 == 0.001
  , {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1,1}, {z, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

I suggest to try the following values : 0.1   0.01   0.001

Comment: Now that I see the suggestion it seems obvious!  Thanks.

Comment: Alternatively try `RegionPlot3D[-# < x^2/2 + x y + y^2/2 + z^2 < #, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 
    1}, {z, -1, 1}, PlotPoints -> 50, MaxRecursion -> 4, 
   Mesh -> False] &[.001]`